# c++ visual studio 2010 exe in resource get Rebased?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, rebase

Has anyone noticed that if you import an exe as resource it gets rebased and also seems that its PE header gets rebuilt?

There are times that this is irritating. Does anybody knows how to disable the rebasing!?

steps to reproduce in c++:

1) compile a hello world and manually set its base address (in properties) to lets say 0x1000000

2) make a second project and include the hello world into resources. Also manually set its base address as above.

3) build second project

4) extract the exe from resources and check it with a Pe editor! it gets set back to 0x400000. Why?!

Comment: according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh7adf4f.aspx, you might have problem with your configuration: please add the linker parameters. Anyhow, I think that are plenty of programs which can rebase PE, so maybe consider try them as well...

Comment: editbin.exe as far as i understand, is an external program that can be run after the compilation. Rebuilding the PE header will not have any effect on the above situation. You missed the point.

Comment: Neither the resource compiler nor the resource APIs know anything about EXE files.  They treat them just like a blob of bytes.  Accordingly, they cannot do anything to change the base address.  The problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you including the EXE as a resource into the second project?

Using these defines:

```
#define BINFILE 222
#define IDR_MYFILE 101
```

If I reference the executable in my .rc file as pointing to the original file, e.g.:

```
IDR_MYFILE BINFILE "S:\\mysource\\t1\\Release\\t1.exe"
```

Then, upon extraction, my embedded EXE resource is not rebased, but maintains what I had built it with.

Comment: yes. thats how i reference the exe file. I am bugging my head for this. I will search for other reasons as Hans Passant suggested.

Comment: Perhaps it's how you're extracting it from the compiled EXE?  I used PE Explorer to extract the exe 1 from exe 2.  And it just worked.

Comment: i used visual studio itself to export the binary file. right-click on the file and select export. should be the same. I think I narrowed down the problem. I used to have an obfuscator. maybe something got left behind because this project is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in a binary builder that'll covert your exe file as a const unsigned char [] array.
That way, VisualStudio will not have a chance to snoop into your resources.

For example, this one: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/juce/files/juce/1.52/prebuilt%20binaries/BinaryBuilder.exe/download